# Yii select with multiple tables with conditions

Tags: php, yii

I am fairly new in yii, how can I do this query with yii?

the query is:

> select table1.userid as userid, table2.name as username, table3.name as tourname from table1, table2, table3 where table1.userid=table2.id and
>   table1.tid=table3.id order by table1.weight, table1.result

Thanks,
Leslie

Comment: You want ot use activerecords o just want to know how to execute query in this format in Yii?

Comment: `Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select table1.userid as userid, table2.name as username, table3.name as tourname from table1, table2, table3 where table1.userid=table2.id and table1.tid=table3.id order by table1.weight, table1.result")->queryAll()`. It's if without AR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use Yii's [Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder) for that.

It would look something like this:

```
$results = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('t1.userid as userid,t2.name as username,t3.name as tourname')
    ->from('table1 t1')
    ->join('table2 t2','on'=> 't1.userid=t2.id') // could be ->leftJoin() as well
    ->join('table3 t3,'on'=>'t1.tid=t3.id')
    ->order('t1.weight,t1,result')
    ->queryAll()
```

Note that I've used joins instead of naming both tables in the where clause. These are two different ways of performing relational queries in SQL. Your method is called *implicit joins* and mine is called *explicit join*.

I used to write implicit joins but now I use mostly explicit joins as they are easier to maintain, read and change if needed.

More info on [CDBCommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand) here.

Answer (score 1):

Ineersa was correct. The most direct answer to the question is:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select table1.userid as userid, table2.name as username, table3.name as tourname from table1, table2, table3 where table1.userid=table2.id and table1.tid=table3.id order by table1.weight, table1.result")->queryAll();
```

But I think you should take advantage of Yii's ability to have relationships so that you can access this information better.